# Correct way to target button elements inside jquery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-delegation

I have jQuery elements `popup` and `buttons`, `buttons` is a child of `popup`.

`buttons` contains `<button>` elements which I want to attach a click event to.

So I write the following code to do so:

```
buttons.children("button").on("click", function() {
    //I'm magic
}
```

But sadly the content of `buttons`can be dynamically changed, buttons can be added and removed :/

So I solved that by writing:

```
buttons.on("click", "button", function() {
    //I'm magic
}
```

But `buttons` itself can be added and removed from `popup`. After `buttons` is removed from and added back to `popup` above code does no longer work :/

The following code seems to solve it:

```
popup.on("click", "button", function() {
    //I'm magic
}
```

But this also triggers when a `<button>` is clicked that's inside `popup` but not inside `buttons`.

How to trigger it only when a `<button>` is inside `buttons` is clicked?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: That's impossible to read. Please post a simple MCVE.

Comment: post your html so its easy for us to check

Comment: Please provide html / js you have until now. Thanks

Comment: There is no need for any html, js. It's a clear question about event delegation in jquery. If it's to complicated move along.

Comment: but it is nice to have html so that we can use proper selector when defining event delegation

Comment: Proper selector??! The whole idea of jquery elements is that there is no need for any classes or ids since you can always reference to the jquery object.

Comment: Then you will need to manually add the event listener as the `buttons` collection changes. The solutions given below work because the "parent" element is already defined and it is just checking for clicks inside of it and its target -- because that never changes.

Comment: @adam-beck nah I was thinking about doing that but the solution by @barmar seems to solve the issue by checking if the button is inside ``buttons`` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a class to all the `buttons` elements, and refer to that in the delegation.

```
popup.on("click", ".buttons button", function() {
    ...
});
```

OK, here's how you might be able to do it without adding classes:

```
popup.on("click", "button", function() {
    var clickedButton = this;
    buttons.each(function(i, aButton) {
        if ($.contains(aButton, clickedButton)) {
            // I'm magic
            return false; // stop looping
        }
    });
});
```

This uses delegation to trigger on any button in `popup`. Then when the code is triggered, it searches through all the `buttons` to see if this button is within one of them. If so, it executes the code you want, and breaks out of the loop.

Comment: The other solution is to redo the delegation every time you update `buttons`, which seems even harder.

Comment: Why isn't that a real solution? We're telling you how to make use of jQuery delegation. It depends on the HTML being structured a particular way.

Comment: I'm not asking how event delegation works...And we're not talking about html elements but jquery objects...

Comment: jQuery objects represent DOM elements.

Comment: O.o jQuery objects represent dom elements and unique jquery properties like an unique jquery id etc.. Anyway your code seems to be better in the aspect of ``buttons`` since it keep in mind that ``buttons`` can also be a collection of elements instead of one.

Comment: I edited your answer to fix some issues, after the edit has been approved I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: Seems the reviewer rejected the edit for some insane reason :S

Comment: I rejected it as well. `break` doesn't work inside `.each()`, `return false` is the way to break out of those loops. Your other changes were just cosmetic and unnecessary.

Comment: Ah my bad I thought it required ``break`` to stop the loop but after looking at the jquery reference it's a ``return false`` indeed. I thought that using a return would also unnecessarily stop the code after the each loop ^^

Comment: I accepted your answer since it does exactly what's needed without adding additional classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking parent class before executing onclick handler:

```
popup.on("click", "button", function() {  
    if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('buttons') ) {
        //I'm magic
    }
}
```

Comment: It still attaches a onclick event to all ``<button>`` elements inside ``popup``. Also your code requires adding a unnecessary class which is never a good idea...

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution I came up with afterwards but that looks a bit messy since it still attaches a click event to all the `<button>` elements inside `popup`.

```
popup.on("click", "button", function() {  
    if($.contains(buttons[0], $(this)[0])) {
        //I'm magic
    }
}
```

The code that would do exactly what I want but doesn't work is:

```
popup.on("click", buttons.find("button"), function() {  
    //I'm magic
}
```

Comment: What is `buttons` ?

Comment: @NikolayErmakov It's a variable in the OP's script.

Comment: This solution will only work for the first button in `buttons`.

Comment: exactly!!!  `this code requires adding a unnecessary "buttons" which is never a good idea`  and we dont know what that buttons is .. i know its a OP's variable.. but what?? ha ha ha :)

Comment: @Barmar Right )) Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar Oh god, you don't seriously think that ``[0]`` refers to the first element?? It's refers to the dom element inside the jquery object. I expected more of stackoverflow :/

Comment: I know what it refers to. If `buttons` is a jQuery object with a collection of elements, `buttons[0]` is the first DOM element, `buttons[1]` is the second DOM element, and so on.

Comment: @Barmar No, ``buttons`` is a jquery object with a html element called ``<whatever>*content here*</whatever>``. Inside that html element are the ``<button>`` elements. But inside the jquery object (using [0]) is the dom element.

Comment: There's nothing in the question that says that `buttons` only refers to a single element, so I didn't assume such a restriction. See my answer that allows for multiple elements in `buttons`.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah my bad, I forgot that ``buttons`` could have multiple elements with ``<button>`` elements inside. I edited your answer to fix some small issues.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood. Here is a solution. Delegate click event of `button` inside `buttons` (`"#buttons button"`) to popup. I have used id  in the fiddle. You might have class there.

```
$('#popup').on("click","#buttons button", function(){
  alert('click');
})
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/mLgyce7x/)

Comment: This code requires adding id's to my elements which isn't a real solution to the problem.

Comment: @seahorsepip  Are you kidding me!!!! thats why we asked for your HTML...:).. so we exactly know what you have there.

Comment: The html can be anything, this is not a html question but a jquery element question. The jquery elements might not even be in the dom yet when the click event is attached.

Comment: @seahorsepip The point is that delegation requires that you attach the event to a static element, and then provide a selector that matches the elements you want to trigger on. This means you need to design your classes to match what you want to do.

Comment: @seahorsepip if it is not a html question then why adding an ids or class (from other answer) in your html matters to you. You know solution is on click delegation + the best part, you tagged your question as `HTML`... ;) :)

Answer (score -1):

I rebuilt the app by your description and it seems to me that it works.

I used a div as an element but you get the idea.

**Quick Brief:** Press any button and it will trigger the click event (hide / show the message). When you press "Remove", the "buttons" div will be removed and will be appended to "popup", so there will be no events left on it, therefore we need to add the event once again. This is not best practice, but it gets the job done.

I hope this helped and that I answered your question.

```js
// When Buttons Div is clicked, the message is hidden / shown
$("#buttons").on("click", function() {
    if($("#txt").is(":visible")){
   $("#txt").hide();
  }
  else{
   $("#txt").show();
  }
});

// When the Remove Button is pressed, "Buttons" will be deleted and appended to Popup
$("#modify").on("click", function(){
  $("#buttons").remove();
  
  // Ignore this... this is the code which can be placed in a function
  $("#popup" ).append('<div id="buttons"><FORM><SELECT name="element"><OPTION value="button">Button</OPTION></SELECT><INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/><span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span></FORM><button type="button">Switch Magic 1</button><button type="button">Switch Magic 2</button><button type="button">Switch Magic 3</button><button type="button">Switch Magic 4</button></div>' );
  
  
  $("#buttons").on("click", function() {
    if($("#txt").is(":visible")){
   $("#txt").hide();
  }
  else{
   $("#txt").show();
   $("#buttons").remove();
  }
 });
});

function add(type) {

 //Create an input type dynamically.
 var element = document.createElement("input");

 //Assign different attributes to the element.
 element.setAttribute("type", type);
 element.setAttribute("value", type);
 element.setAttribute("name", type);


 var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

 //Append the element in page (in span).
 foo.appendChild(element);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add(type) {

 //Create an input type dynamically.
 var element = document.createElement("input");

 //Assign different attributes to the element.
 element.setAttribute("type", type);
 element.setAttribute("value", type);
 element.setAttribute("name", type);


 var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

 //Append the element in page (in span).
 foo.appendChild(element);

}
</SCRIPT>
<div id="popup">
<button id="modify" type="button">
Remove
</button>
<div id="buttons">
<FORM>
<SELECT name="element">
 <OPTION value="button">Button</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>
<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
</FORM>
<button type="button">
Switch Magic 1
</button>
<button type="button">
Switch Magic 2
</button>
<button type="button">
Switch Magic 3
</button>
<button type="button">
Switch Magic 4
</button>
</div>
</div>
<label id="txt">I'm magic!</label>
```

Comment: I often understood better from other peoples' demos. And I explained the solution, therefore I believe it is good enough. No need for hate.